# How to modify the author's color through \renewcommand

Tags: color, titles, author, renewcommand

I retrieved the method \renewcommand MakeTitle to set the color of the title.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\title}[1]{\renewcommand{\@title}{\color{\@titlecolor}#1}}
\newcommand{\@titlecolor}{red}
\newcommand{\titlecolor}[1]{\renewcommand{\@titlecolor}{#1}}
\makeatother
```

This was very successful and worked for me. I used a similar command to modify the author, but only part of the author changed the color.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\makeatletter

\renewcommand{\author}[1]{\renewcommand{\@author}{\color{\@authorcolor}#1}}
\newcommand{\@authorcolor}{red}
\newcommand{\authorcolor}[1]{\renewcommand{\@authorcolor}{#1}}
\makeatother
\title{My Title}
\author{Author One$^1$ \\ Author Two$^2$ 
  \\
    \normalsize{$^1$Organization 1}\\
    \normalsize{$^2$Organization 2}\\
    \\
    \normalsize{Emails: 111@mail.com, 222@mail.com}\thanks{Thanks} }


\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

output：

[image]

Could you please design a better scheme to change the color of all contents in author (including \thanks, etc.)? By the way, SINCE I have a lot of documents to work with, I'd like to do that through renewcommand.

Comment: Can use Lua to process the code (add color-changing command every `\\`) and print back.

Comment: Formatting instructions belong to `\maketitle` rather than `\author` or `\title`

Answer (score 1):

You essentially have to understand the structure of the title construction. The `\title` (or `\@title`) typically contains only a single element, so colouring it is fairly easy/straight forward. However, since the `\author` (or `\@author`) could include multiple members/elements, it's set by default inside a `tabular`; this allows you to use `\\` to separate authors. This does, however, provide limited scope. In fact, each cell forms a group, which explains why your change in colour only applies to the *first* cell.

Knowing the `\@author` is structured like a `tabular`, the following updates your redefinition of `\author` to know set the `\@author` within a (nested) `tabular`, allowing the colour to apply across the entire (nested) author list.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\author}[1]{\renewcommand{\@author}{%
  \color{\@authorcolor}
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    #1
  \end{tabular}}}
\newcommand{\@authorcolor}{red}
\newcommand{\authorcolor}[1]{\renewcommand{\@authorcolor}{#1}}
\makeatother

\title{A Title}
\author{%
  Author One\textsuperscript{1} \\
  Author Two\textsuperscript{2} \\
  \textsuperscript{1}Organization 1 \\
  \textsuperscript{2}Organization 2 \\
  \\
  Emails: 111@mail.com, 222@mail.com\thanks{Thanks}
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers, your answers work well on my task! In addition, I would like to ask you how to renewcommand the color of /thanks.

Comment: Hello, I found a problem. It seems that I cannot handle commands of this type \author[1]{author name}.

Comment: @happy: And what would `\author[1]{author name}` represent? What does the optional argument do?

Comment: Yes, I found that when there are parameters, it will not change the color or produce wrong results.